# How to call object's method from another object in Java?

Tags: java, android, class, methods, call

I have 2 classes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute("string");
    }

    public void setSomething(int param) {
        // ... some code here ...
    }
}
```

and

**MyAsyncTask.java**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
        return "Someting here";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
         // how to call setSomething(param) from here?
    }
}
```

How to call setSomething(param) from MyAsyncTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a reference of `MainActivity` to `MyAsyncTask`:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyAsyncTask(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever creating an instance of `MyAsyncTask` inside the class `MainActivity`, pass `this` (`MainActivity` instance) to the constructor:

```
new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
```

Comment: Damn it! The constructor, right :) Everything works just perfect. Exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general, the way to call it is to have a reference to an object of type MainActivity and to call this method on it. Whether that's a good idea in this particular Android scenario, is another question.

Comment: Yeah, but I had no idea how to pass the reference :) Thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth looking into using an async library.

Using a library to help handle async callbacks can be super helpful for this as you can start the spinner, call your api, then stop the spinner in either the onSuccess function, or your success callback method in your class.

This is the one I usually use:

**[LoopJ's Async HTTP Callback Library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)**

This will handle GET and POST requests with a lot of cool features such as custom timeouts, JSON format, onSuccess() and onFailure() methods, etc. There's a lot of working examples of this library too!

Comment: Wow that's interesting. I'll take a look... Thanks!